# Regex: match certain word in string enclosed by parentheses

Tags: python, regex

I'm scraping the window title of a program to get the current state using python. The title of the targeted window is formatted like this:

```
[File1.xyz] (Saved file1.xyz)
```

I want to match the "Saved" but ignore the rest of it, but have to make sure it's in the parentheses.

My approached looks like this

```
\[([^)]+)\] \((\bSaved\b)\)
```

but it only matches (Saved) and not (Saved file1.xyz).

**Edit:** 
The program is processing a file and displays the current progress in the title bar. I want to match "Saved" to determine that the program is finished, in this case the window title would be: (Saved untitled.stl)
It's not always the first word so I can't use this to match it.

Comment: Could you be more specific about what exactly you're trying to match? It's hard to derive a pattern from a single example. Are you looking for the first word that appears within parentheses? Do you want to avoid such matches if they aren't preceded by a square bracket block?

Comment: I want to match the specific "Saved" within the parentheses. The program is processing a file and the current progress is displayed in the window title, e.g. (Saved untitled.stl), (34% untitled.stl), (Stopped untitled.stl). I'll edit my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex has no expression for the actual filename in the second part. I think you want to do this:

```
\[([^)]+)\] \((Saved)[^)]+\)
```

This would give `File1.xyz` for the first and `Saved` for the second group of the match.

See [here](https://regex101.com/r/YZXjie/2) for yourself.